# Make .php files show as subdirectories in the address bar, hiding the actual filetype/name?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Okay I was able to get my previous question a solution, but now I've come into a roadblock of sorts. My website plans on having content on many different pages, and I was wondering if there was a way to make every .php file show domain.com/filename/ Showing a sub directory rather than the filename.php

I know below makes it so test.php shows up as domain.com/test/ but to do it this way I would need to edit .htaccess for every file I wish to show as a sub directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^test/?$ test.php [L,NC]
```

Oh and no content is within the sub directory(if they even exist as folders on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some recursive attempt without RewriteCond:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule (.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for hiding .php extension:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo/
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R,L]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo/ to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some good knowledge in Object Oriented programming in PHP. To achieve such a URL, you need a dispatching pattern, the most ideal for your case is the front controller.

Here is an example of a class controller:

```
class ControllerIndex {
    public $urlmap = array(
        'welcome' => 'WelcomePage'
        );
}
```

With the front controller, all requests go through a global mapping mechanism, and is then delegated to a handler. A handler will then have the form of a class, rather than a file.

The front controller offers more meaningful/pretty URLs. You would have something like http://domain.com/welcome/ instead of http://domain.com/welcome.php